# Botão com borda arredondada e sombra usando 9 patch

Tags: android

Bom dia!
Gostaria de colocar sombra nas imagens e botões do meu aplicativo e estou tentando usar os recursos do 9 patch. Porém não está dando muito certo, a altura do png que estou usando como sombra sempre fica maior:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**xml do `ImageButton`:**

```
<ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnentrarfb"
        android:background="@drawable/shadow"
        android:src="@drawable/botaofacebook" />
```

Outro problema que estou tendo é com os botões, pois já tenho um estilo definido para eles e usei como background um xml pra deixar as bordas arredondadas, então não estou sabendo como colocar a sombra. Tentei, mas não está tendo efeito nenhum, fica apenas com as bordas arredondadas.

**styleButton.xml:**

```
<style name="styleButton">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/screen_border</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/icons</item>
    </style>
```

**screen_border.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/shadow"/>
    <item>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/primary" />
            <corners
                android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
                android:topRightRadius="10dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**xml do botão:**

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnentrar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:text="@string/btn_entrar"
        style="@style/estiloBotao"
        android:textColor="@color/branco" />
```